# How to avoid getting an error of str and int using Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print ("what is your name")
MyName = input()
print ('nice to meet you, ' + MyName)
print ('what is your age, ' + MyName)
age = input()
if(age<18):
    print ("teenager")
```

Everytime I answered the question "what is your age" it says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 6, in 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Can someone help, please, to resolve it?

Comment: Your age is of type `str`. By default the `input()` data type is `string`. You can do `age=int(input())`.

Comment: To add go @Goku-standswithPalestine 's comment, you can convert a string to an integer as follows:
`age = int(input())`

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `age` at line 5, you are setting it to a str (a string) because input() will always return a str. You can convert it to an int (a number) by changing line 5 to `age = int(input())`. Although this can cause errors if the user enters some that is not a string. Here is your changed code:

```
print ("what is your name")
MyName = input()
print ('nice to meet you, ' + MyName)
print ('what is your age, ' + MyName)
age = int(input())
if(age<18):
    print ("teenager")
```

Answer (score 0):

the 'input' function always returns a string, you nedd to convert it into an integer with the 'int' function
age=int(input('what is your age?'))

Answer (score 0):

Input function returns string by default so you need to convert age to integer. Try this, it works:

```
MyName = input(("what is your name: "))
print ('nice to meet you, ' + MyName)
print('what is your age, ' + MyName )
age = int(input())
if(age<18):
    print ("teenager")
```

Comment: Not only does it return a string *by default*, but it *always* returns a string.

Answer (score -2):

```
print ("what is your name")
MyName = input()
print ('nice to meet you, ' , MyName)
print ('what is your age, ' , MyName)
age = input()
if(age<18):
    print ("teenager")
```

Use this code that will remove your error.